# How to get xmllint to return just the XML Element attribute?

Tags: xml, bash, xmllint

```
<Hosts>
    <Host Host_FQDN="myhost00.com">
        <ip_Address>text</ip_Address>
        <ip_Address>text</ip_Address>
        <ip_Address>text</ip_Address>
        <Host_Directory_To_Clean Perform="text">
            <Perform_Deletes>true</Perform_Deletes>
            <Delete_Files_AbsolutePath>String</Delete_Files_AbsolutePath>
            <Delete_Files_Recursively>true</Delete_Files_Recursively>
            <Delete_Files_Selection>String</Delete_Files_Selection>
            <Delete_Files_Selection>String</Delete_Files_Selection>
            <Delete_Files_Selection>String</Delete_Files_Selection>
        </Host_Directory_To_Clean>
        <Host_FileSystem_Backup Perform="text">
            <Perform_Backup>False</Perform_Backup>
            <Backup_Full_Path>String</Backup_Full_Path>
            <Backup_File_Name>String</Backup_File_Name>
        </Host_FileSystem_Backup>
    </Host>
</Hosts>
<Hosts>
    <Host Host_FQDN=" myhost01.com">
        <ip_Address>text</ip_Address>
        <ip_Address>text</ip_Address>
        <ip_Address>text</ip_Address>
        <Host_Directory_To_Clean Perform="text">
            <Perform_Deletes>true</Perform_Deletes>
            <Delete_Files_AbsolutePath>String</Delete_Files_AbsolutePath>
            <Delete_Files_Recursively>true</Delete_Files_Recursively>
            <Delete_Files_Selection>String</Delete_Files_Selection>
            <Delete_Files_Selection>String</Delete_Files_Selection>
            <Delete_Files_Selection>String</Delete_Files_Selection>
        </Host_Directory_To_Clean>
        <Host_FileSystem_Backup Perform="text">
            <Perform_Backup>N</Perform_Backup>
            <Backup_Full_Path>String</Backup_Full_Path>
            <Backup_File_Name>String</Backup_File_Name>
        </Host_FileSystem_Backup>
    </Host>
</Hosts>
<Hosts>
    <Host Host_FQDN=" myhost02.com">
        <ip_Address>text</ip_Address>
        <ip_Address>text</ip_Address>
        <ip_Address>text</ip_Address>
        <Host_Directory_To_Clean Perform="text">
            <Perform_Deletes>true</Perform_Deletes>
            <Delete_Files_AbsolutePath>String</Delete_Files_AbsolutePath>
            <Delete_Files_Recursively>true</Delete_Files_Recursively>
            <Delete_Files_Selection>String</Delete_Files_Selection>
            <Delete_Files_Selection>String</Delete_Files_Selection>
            <Delete_Files_Selection>String</Delete_Files_Selection>
        </Host_Directory_To_Clean>
        <Host_FileSystem_Backup Perform="text">
            <Perform_Backup>NO</Perform_Backup>
            <Backup_Full_Path>String</Backup_Full_Path>
            <Backup_File_Name>String</Backup_File_Name>
        </Host_FileSystem_Backup>
    </Host>
</Hosts>
```

I am trying to get an xmllint –xpath expression to return just the value of an XML Element.
I have tried…

```
xmllint --xpath string(//Hosts/Host)[1]/@Host_FQDN /myFile.xml
xmllint --xpath “string(//Hosts/Host)[1]/@Host_FQDN” /myFile.xml
xmllint --xpath (string(//Hosts/Host)[1]/@Host_FQDN) /myFile.xml
xmllint --xpath “(string(//Hosts/Host)[1]/@Host_FQDN)” /myFile.xml
```

But the result is one or more of the following errors.
**bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

XPath error : Invalid type

XPath evaluation failure**

If the following is used the XML Element attribute name and value is return.  I just want the value.

```
xmllint --xpath (//Hosts/Host)[1]/@Host_FQDN /myFile.xml
```

Results below have a leading space.
 **Host_FQDN="myhost.com"**

What I find odd is that the count() function works just fine.  See the example below.

```
xmllint --xpath count(//Hosts/Host)[1]/@Host_FQDN /myFile.xml
```

The code snippet that invokes the xmllint command in a BASH Script is below.

```
       unset wwString
       wwString="xmllint --xpath string(//"
       wwString="$wwString$xmlElementName)"
       wwString="$wwString["
       wwString="$wwString$i]/@"
       wwString="$wwString$xmlElementAttributeName "
       wwString="$wwString$propertiesFileFullPath"
       wwString="$wwString/"
       wwString="$wwString$fullXMLpropertiesFileName"
       wwExtracted=$(${wwString})
```

Comment: Please post valid XML with only one root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

The char `(` is recognized by bash to be a bash token, so you would have to escape it, but that is not what you want. You want to pass the XPath expression to `xmllint`, so the solution is to put the expression in brackets:

```
xmllint --xpath '//Hosts/Host[1]/@Host_FQDN' myFile.xml
```

Your second error was to *interrupt* the `string(...)` function in the middle of your XPath expression. So a correct version of your attempts would look like

```
xmllint --xpath "string(//Hosts/Host[1]/@Host_FQDN)" myFile.xml
```

The above expression returns only the string value of the first `Host` element's `Host_FQDN` attribute.

---

**Just some kind of a horrid note:**
You used the `“` quote char instead of the `"` quote char!!!
That could have been a reason for your malfunctions as well.